# Extreme low-priority SELECT query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, priority-queue

Is it possible to issue an (expensive, but low-priority) SELECT query to mySQL in such a way that if an UPDATE query appears in the queue, mySQL will immediately terminate the query, and re-append it to the end of the queue?

If re-appending to the queue is not possible, I'm happy with simply killing the SELECT query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not really.

I am not sure exactly what you need, but my guess is that you need to either optimize the SELECT to not lock an entire table, or get the replication going and do the SELECT on the slave rather than the master.

You could theoretically find out what the MySQL process ID is of the SELECT query, and in your application send a KILL before you do any update.

Comment: Even if I'm locking only part of the table (which I'll have to look into) I'd still hate to risk holding up one of our UPDATEs.  It is a very low-priority scan looking for errors and collecting statistics.  I've considered doing the scan in chunks using OFFSET and LIMIT, but the answer to a previous question of mine indicates that this is almost as expensive as a full scan for OFFSETs near the end of the table.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389759/memory-efficient-built-in-sqlalchemy-iterator-generator

Comment: I'll look into replication, but it seems like overkill as it is a very large table.   I'd simply rather not have the query run than to hold up an UPDATE.

Comment: Perhaps you can split up your query, but based on an indexed column and a WHERE field

Comment: That seems to also take a fair amount of time and still locks part of the table.  I'm very interested in what you mean by "not really" and why you do not say "definitely not"! :)

Comment: @Paul "not really" == "not in this reality" == "definitely not"

Answer (score 0):

Well, sort of maybe.

A client runs an application which occasionally throws out queries that completely kill performance for everything else on the server.  We have monitoring and if we've got a suitable person ready to react, we can deal to that query manually, and we learn about the problems in the app by doing things that way.

But to prevent major outages if noone is on the ball, we have an automated script which terminates long running queries, so the server does recover in the event that noone is available to intervene within 15 minutes.

Far from ideal, but that's where things are currently at with this project, and it does prevent the occasional extended outages that used to occur.  We can only move just so fast with fixing up the problem queries.

Anyway, you could run something similar, that looks at the running queries and recognises when you have an update waiting on one of your large selects, and in that event it kills the select.  Doing this sort of check a few times a minute is not overly expensive.  I'd want to do a bit of testing before running.

So, whether you can solve your problem this way depends on what your tolerance is for how long an update can be delayed.  Running this every minute (as we do) is no problem at all.  Running it every second would noticeably add to the overall load.  You'd need to test how far you can reasonably go in between those points.

This approach means some delay before the select gets pushed out of the way, but it saves you having to build this logic into potentially many different places in your application.

--

Regarding breaking up your query, you're most likely better off restricting the chunks by id range from one or more tables in your query rather than by offset and limit.

--

There may also be good solutions available based on partitioning your tables so that the queries don't collide as badly.  Make sure you have a very good grasp on what you are doing for this though.