# SQLAlchemy and going through a large result set

Tags: pagination, sqlalchemy

I need to read data from all of the rows of a large table, but I don't want to pull all of the data into memory at one time. Is there a SQLAlchemy function that will handle paging? That is, pull several rows into memory and then fetch more when necessary.

I understand you can do this with `limit` and `offset` as [this article](http://pythonguy.wordpress.com/2011/08/17/sqlalchemy-tips-performance/) suggests, but I'd rather not handle that if I don't have to.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389759/memory-efficient-built-in-sqlalchemy-iterator-generator). In short, you can use the [`yield_per`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html?highlight=yield_per#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.yield_per) operator.

Comment: The answers on the referenced page are not as good as the ones on this page.

Answer (score 41):

If you are using Flask-SqlAlchemy, see the [paginate](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery.paginate) method of `query`. `paginate` offers several method to simplify pagination.

```
record_query = Record.query.paginate(page, per_page, False)
total = record_query.total
record_items = record_query.items
```

First page should be 1 otherwise the `.total` returns exception divided by zero

Comment: Disregard my other comments, this works excellently as is, I was just doing `dict(**request.args)` stupidly in an unrelated area and getting unexpected results.

Comment: No this could still be a bad idea as if you check the source they are using limit and offset. Now if the offset value is too big then the database would go through all of those values thus causing a performance problem..

Answer (score 19):

If you aren't using Flask, you can use SqlAlchemy function 'slice' or a combo of 'limit' & 'offset', as mentioned [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html?highlight=order_by#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.order_by). E.g.:

```
some_query = Query([TableBlaa])
query = some_query.limit(number_of_rows_per_page).offset(page_number*number_of_rows_per_page)
#  -- OR --
query = some_query.slice(page_number*number_of_rows_per_page, (page_number*number_of_rows_per_page)+number_of_rows_per_page)
current_pages_rows = session.execute(query).fetchall()
```

Comment: Limit offset is bad if the offset is high as it has go through all of the previous rows to fetch the offsetted rows thus causing a performance problem

Comment: @AbhishekJebaraj if we don't use limit offset ? any recommend ???

Comment: @tyan Datetime or any other suitable filters are a good way to do them. Because limit offset always fetches the rows and then offsets. Better to filter them and then fetch the filtered ones instead.

Comment: proper pagination also returns useful information such as total number of records, number of records in the current page, whether this is the first page or the last page, etc.

Comment: the logic here seems wrong. It should be something like
`some_query.limit(number_of_rows_per_page).offset((page_number - 1) * number_of_rows_per_page)`
The slice logic also seems wrong...

Comment: @jgozal you logic also seems to be wrong offset should be equal to: ((page_number - 1) * page_size)+1
For page 1 - offset should be 1 not 0 and for page 2- offset should be 11 not 10

Answer (score 10):

If you are building an api to use with **ReactJs**, **vueJs** or other frontEnd framework, you can process like:

Notice:

`page`: current page that you need

`error_out`: Not display errors

`max_per_page` or `per_page` : the **limit**

Documentaion:  [SqlAchemy pagination](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.Pagination)

```
    record_query = Record.query.paginate(page=*Number*, error_out=False, max_per_page=15)

    result = dict(datas=record_query.items, 
                   total=record_query.total, 
                   current_page=record_query.page,
                   per_page=record_query.per_page)
```

On  **record_query** you can use :

*next(error_out=False)*

> Returns a Pagination object for the next page.

**next_num**

> Number of the next page

**page = None**

> the current page number (1 indexed)

**pages**

> The total number of pages

**per_page = None**

> the number of items to be displayed on a page.

**prev(error_out=False)**

> Returns a Pagination object for the previous page.

**prev_num**

> Number of the previous page.

**query = None**

> the unlimited query object that was used to create this pagination
>   object.

**total = None**

> the total number of items matching the query

Hope it help you!

Comment: Please note that this is Flask-SQLAchemy and not standard SqlAchemy.