# sqlalchemy query all items, I wanna a generator or iterable object, not list, how to

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

some code like below:

```
session.query(MODEL).all()
```

it will return all items with the type **list**

this means that, it will take a lots memory if there are a large amount items?

How can i got a iterable object, but not list.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389759/memory-efficient-built-in-sqlalchemy-iterator-generator

Answer (score 1):

Year,  not use `all()` , and the result is a generator

and thanks @dm03514