# sqlalchemy: express relationship which depends on len of collection child in joined entity?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

How do I express relationship which depends on len of collection child in joined entity?

In below example, parent entity is **AlgoOrder**. Child entity is Order. And **PrivateTrade** is child entity of **Order**.

AlgoOrder --> Order --> PrivateTrade

The problem I am having is with "***orders_pending_private_trade_update***".

```
class AlgoOrder(DbModel):
  __tablename__ = "algo_order"

  id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
  ... stuff ...

  # https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/loading_relationships.html
  open_orders = orm.relation(Order, primaryjoin=and_(Order.algo_order_id == id, Order.status == 'OPEN'), lazy='select')
  orders_pending_private_trade_update = orm.relation(Order, primaryjoin=and_(Order.algo_order_id == id, , Order.status == 'CLOSED', len(Order.private_trades)==0), lazy='select')

  @property
  def pending_orders(self):
    return self.open_orders + self.orders_pending_private_trade_update


class Order(DbModel):
    __tablename__ = "order_hist"

    algo_order_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey("algo_order.id"))
    ... stiff ...

    private_trades = orm.relation(PrivateTrade, primaryjoin=and_(PrivateTrade.order_id == order_id))


class PrivateTrade(DbModel):
  __tablename__ = "private_trade"

  id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
  order_id = sa.Column(sa.String, sa.ForeignKey("order_hist.order_id"))
```

In particular, the error at ***"orders_pending_private_trade_update"*** was with "**len**" on Order.private_trades:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: _run_module_as_main) object of type 'InstrumentedAttribute' has no len()
```

So, I tried:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import func
orders_pending_private_trade_update = orm.relation(Order, primaryjoin=and_(Order.algo_order_id == id, Order.status == 'CLOSED', func.count(Order.private_trades)==0), lazy='select', viewonly=True)
```

But then error was *"foreign key columns are present in neither the parent nor the child's mapped tables"*:

```
Can't determine relationship direction for relationship 'AlgoOrder.orders_pending_private_trade_update' - foreign key columns are present in neither the parent nor the child's mapped tables <class 'sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError'> Can't determine relationship direction for relationship 'AlgoOrder.orders_pending_private_trade_update' - foreign key columns are present in neither the parent nor the child's mapped tables
```

I checked my tables, I do have them:

```
op.create_table(
    'algo_order',
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), primary_key=True),
    ...

op.create_table(
    'order_hist',
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), primary_key=True),
    sa.Column('algo_order_id', sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey("algo_order.id")),
    ...
op.create_table(
    'private_trade',
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), primary_key=True),
    sa.Column('order_id', sa.String(), sa.ForeignKey("order_hist.order_id"))
    ...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it, but syntax pretty ugly: I used closed_order.**session** to do a new Query

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.orm as orm
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import func
import sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql as psql
from sqlalchemy.ext.mutable import MutableDict
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import and_

class AlgoOrder(DbModel):
    __tablename__ = "algo_order"

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ... other stuff ...
    open_orders = orm.relation(Order, primaryjoin=and_(Order.algo_order_id == id, Order.status == 'OPEN'), lazy='select')
    closed_orders = orm.relation(Order, primaryjoin=and_(Order.algo_order_id == id, Order.status == 'CLOSED'), lazy='dynamic', viewonly=True)

    @property
    def orders_pending_private_trade_update(self):
        order_ids_with_no_private_trades = [ order.id for order in list(self.closed_orders.session.query(Order.id, func.count(PrivateTrade.id).label('count_private_trades')).join(PrivateTrade, isouter=True).group_by(Order.id).having(func.count(PrivateTrade.id) == 0).all())]
        orders_with_no_private_trades = self.closed_orders.session.query(Order).filter(Order.id.in_(order_ids_with_no_private_trades)).order_by(Order.id.desc()).limit(1000).all()
        return orders_with_no_private_trades

    @property
    def pending_orders(self):
        return list(self.open_orders) + list(self.orders_pending_private_trade_update)
```

I also don't like "first(100)" as an attempt to limit number of rows fetched. And how/when you dispose of the list to prevent memory leak? I think above approach is bad. Should use [generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389759/memory-efficient-built-in-sqlalchemy-iterator-generator) instead of returning list.

Essentially raw sql what I am looking for is a generator which returns below:

```
select
    order_id,
    cnt
    from (
        select
            order_hist.id,
            order_hist.order_id,
            count(private_trade.id) cnt
            from order_hist
            left join private_trade on private_trade.order_id = order_hist.order_id
            where order_hist.status in ('CLOSED', 'CANCELLED')
            group by order_hist.id, order_hist.order_id
    ) src
    where
    cnt=0
```

Any better way to do this? I think my solution shows the sqlalchemy syntax but it's computationally inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Here's solution using **generator** instead to avoid MemoryError:

```
def order_hist_missing_private_trade_get(engine):
    order_hist_missing_private_trade_sql = '''
            select
                order_id,
                cnt
                from (
                    select
                        order_hist.id,
                        order_hist.order_id,
                        count(private_trade.id) cnt
                        from order_hist
                        left join private_trade on private_trade.order_id = order_hist.order_id
                        where order_hist.status in ('CLOSED', 'CANCELLED')
                        group by order_hist.id, order_hist.order_id
                ) src
                where
                cnt=0
            '''
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389759/memory-efficient-built-in-sqlalchemy-iterator-generator
        conn.execution_options(stream_results=True)
        rs = conn.execute(order_hist_missing_private_trade_sql)
        while True:
            batch = rs.fetchmany(10000)
            for row in batch:
                order_id = row['order_id']
                yield order_id
```

Usage:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

connstr : str = "postgresql://postgres:your_secret@localhost/postgres"
engine = create_engine(connstr)
generator = order_hist_missing_private_trade_get(engine)
while True:
    order_id = next(generator)
    print(f"order_id: {order_id}")
```