# Is for item in query() equivalent to for item in query().all() in SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Outside of the for loop, `query()` returns a Query object while `all()` execute the query and store the result in a list, according to the document. My question is when in a loop, the query object is obviously executed, is there still any benefit to use `query()` over `query().all()`?

Comment: This question has been asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078383/sqlalchemy-difference-between-query-and-query-all-in-for-loops

Comment: Hi, @Green Chili. I did read that post. It seems `query()` is more memory friendly than `query().all()`. Does that mean when looping through rows, it's always better to use `query()`? I really didn't see any benefit of using `all()` in the context of looping.

Comment: there won't be any performance differences really. Not unless you were to break after n number of rows versus looping through millions of records.