# How i can iterate query from SQLAlchemy twice

Tags: python, loops, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I have query using SQLAlchemy ORM:

```
query_category = DBSession.query(Product) \
            .options(defer(Product.stock_qty))\
            .filter(
                Product.categories.any(Category.id == category.id),
                Product.categories.any(Category.id.in_(parent_ids)),
            )
```

I want to iterate this query in loop twice using for .. in like this:

```
for i in query_category:
...do something

for i in query_category:
    ...do something else
```

I understand that this is generator, but i don't know how to 'restart' this generator. I am try to use `seek(0)` like with file, but it is not work. So what command should i use for `restart` my query

Comment: could you not do both things while iterating once? is the second iteration dependent on the first one finishing?

Comment: If you must have 2 separate loops, materialize the results to a list using [`Query.all()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.all), [just to avoid some overhead of doing the ORM handling again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078383/sqlalchemy-difference-between-query-and-query-all-in-for-loops). The query object can be iterated over multiple times as is. No need to "restart" it.

Comment: I want to iterate twice, because i want to see that first things in forloop worked fine

Comment: Note that iterating over the same query object multiple times will issue the query to the DB each time. All the more reason to use `all()`.

Comment: Thanks this is work fine!

Comment: @Ilja Everilä, you can write you answer and i will accept it